# Conversation Started Callback

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

When I start an action:

> OK Google talk To **My Assistant**

It authenticates and runs the welcome intent which loads User Entities that can be used for subsequent questions to API.AI

When I try to start an action:

> OK Google ask **My Assistant** *some question*

It authenticates, but there is no way for me to load the users Entities because I do not have a sessionID for the conversation.

When API.AI tries to evaluate the *some question* it can't because the user entities have not been loaded.

It seems the only option is SlotFilling WebHook ... but I really do not need this (or the complexity it requires) if I have an option to define the  users Entities.

Any way to get the API.AI sessionID (which is defined by Google Actions) before making the first request to API.AI ? Or any other way to get some WebHook called that contains the sessionsID  before API.AI tries to evaluate *some question* ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a solution.
I placed an input context named "EntitiesLoaded" to all of my deep link questions.
Then when I issue:

> OK Google ask My Assistant some question

It calls the Fallback Intent.
In the fallback Intent I do the following:

1. Load the User Entities
2. Set the "EntitiesLoaded" context.
3. Re-Issue the original Query (which was passed to the Fallback extent). This time it will work.

Comment: I forgot to say that my Welcome Intent set the "EntitiesLoaded" context.

Comment: You're re-issuing the query using the API.AI API at the /query endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to preemptively get a session identifier until the session has started. Additionally, deep link phrases in general should be static or rely on entities that API.AI already knows about (not User Entities).

```
Ok Google talk to <invocation_name> about ... <deep_link_phrase>
```

Any dynamic user content will likely have to be provided during the conversation.

You may want to reconsider your design a little bit here based on what experience you're trying to create.